# Jenkins plugin for Github enterprise: how to get new/changed pull request info

Tags: jenkins, plugins, pull-request, github-enterprise

Jenkins have many plugins but their name are very confusing,

so do you know which jenkins plugin can be used to poll new/changed pull request from `Github enterprise`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Github Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin)

Where it states:

> GitHub Enterprise
>
> You can also redefine GitHub url by clicking on Custom GitHub API URL
>   checkbox. Note that credentials are filtered by entered GH url with
>   help of domain requirements. So you can create credentials in
>   different domains and see only credentials that matched by predefined
>   domains.

And to manage the hooks

> Automatic Mode (Jenkins manages hooks for jobs by itself) In this
>   mode, Jenkins will automatically add/remove hook URLs to GitHub based
>   on the project configuration in the background. You'll specify GitHub
>   OAuth token so that Jenkins can login as you to do this.
>
> Step 1. Go to the global configuration and add GitHub Server Config.

Ideally, you would have a separate Jenkins user with an OAUTH token defined in GHE as part of a secret text credential.